# Why asctime(localtime(&ltime)) function does work on gcc 4.8.4 properly and cause problem with gcc 9.4.0

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gcc, makefile, localtime

```
ltime=time(NULL);
sprintf(buffer,"\n%sTwo matrices of size %dx%d have been read. The number of threads is %d \n",asctime(localtime(&ltime)),side_Array,side_Array,val_M);
write(STDOUT_FILENO,buffer,strlen(buffer));
```

This the code that cause problem with output file that threads write into it. I know that localtime is not thread safe function however, i used localtime in gcc 4.8.4 it workes properly. I am sure that localtime is the problem but i don't get it why it doesn't cause problem with gcc 4.8.4 and is there any possible solution with changing makefile?

Here is my main:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ltime=time(NULL);
    sprintf(buffer,"\n%sTwo matrices of size %dx%d have been read. The number of threads is %d \n",asctime(localtime(&ltime)),side_Array,side_Array,val_M);
    write(STDOUT_FILENO,buffer,strlen(buffer));

// reading file, creating arrays

    pthread_mutex_init (&mutex, NULL);


    threadsArr = malloc(sizeof(pthread_t) * val_M);

    for(i = 0; i < val_M; ++i){
        prm_i = malloc(sizeof(*prm_i));
        *prm_i = i;
         pthread_create(&(threadsArr[i]), NULL, threads, prm_i);
    }


    for(i = 0; i < val_M; ++i){
        pthread_join(threadsArr[i],NULL);
    }

    //Threads write result into arr_DFT and because of localtime this calculation gives wrong result.

    for(i = 0; i < side_Array; i++)
    {
       for(j = 0; j < side_Array; j++)
       {
           sprintf(buffer, "%.3f + (%.3fi),",arr_DFT[i][j].real, arr_DFT[i][j].imag);
           write(fd_csv, buffer, strlen(buffer));
       }
       write(fd_csv, newLine, strlen(newLine));
    }


}
```

Here is my thread:

```
void *threads(void *arg1){
    //mathematical calculations

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    ++arrived;
    end = clock();
    time_spend = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    sprintf(printBuffer,"%sThread %d has arrived the rendezvous point in %.2f seconds.\n",asctime(localtime(&ltime)),tempVal+1, time_spend);
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, printBuffer, strlen(printBuffer));


    if(arrived < val_M)
        pthread_cond_wait(&conditionVar, &mutex);

    else
        pthread_cond_broadcast(&conditionVar);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    sprintf(printBuffer,"%sThread %d is advancing the second part.\n",asctime(localtime(&ltime)), tempVal+1);
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, printBuffer, strlen(printBuffer));
    begin = clock();

    // mathematical calculations

    end = clock();
    time_spend = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    sprintf(printBuffer, "%sThread %d has finished the second part in %f seconds \n",asctime(localtime(&ltime)),tempVal+1, time_spend);
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, printBuffer, strlen(printBuffer));
    return NULL;
}
```

Here is my makefile:

```
all: 
    gcc -Wall main.c -o hw5 -pthread -lm

clean:
    rm -f *o && rm -f hw5
```

Comment: What kind of problem?

Comment: Can we please get a [mcve]?

Comment: I have complex program which i can't simplify here but simply i used the asctime(localtime(&ltime)) function before i created threads. I created threades for making some mathematical calculations and store it to an array. At the very end of program i print that array to the output file, because of asctime(localtime(&ltime)) function, it gives wrong result with gcc 9.4.0 but it gives true result with gcc 4.8.4. Also  if I delete asctime(localtime(&ltime)) it gives true result with gcc 9.4.0

Comment: We can't do anything useful with this information. Please post a [mcve]. You don't have to simplify your existing program, you just write a small program from scratch. If the problem is indeed with gcc 9.4.0 handling of `asctime(localtime(&ltime))`, you will be able to wrire one in 5 minutes. If you cannot, then the problem is elsewhere, and we know exactly as much about it as you do.

Comment: I edit the post, hope it is useful

Comment: This is not compilable code. I cannot find errors in something I cannot compile. Please copy your code to an online compiler, add missing #include directives, add missing declarations, fix all the errors, make sure it runs and reproduces the problem, *then* copy the resulting [mcve] to your post.